# Apache custom 404 page: relative links break in sub directories

Tags: apache, http-status-code-404, errordocument

The Apache version is 2.4. In httpd.conf, there is a virtual server with a custom 404 page:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin **
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/**
     ServerName www.**
     ServerAlias **
     ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
</VirtualHost>
```

The 404.html document is on the root directory of the website, and in it, there are relative links and images from the sub directory "imgaes" (`<img src="images/some_img.jpg" />` - relative image links).

If the **request** for the non existent page is done in the root dir, like `www.website.com/not_found`, the images on the 404.html display well, but if the non-existent page was **requested** in a sub directory, like `www.website.com/sub_sir/not_found`, all images and links get broken.

Is there a way to tell Apache to redirect to the 404 page as if it is on root dir, and not display it like it is to the current requested dir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to make your links relative to your public html root, in your case `<img src="/images/some_img.jpg" />`
hope it works :)